# I want to populate another collection document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to populate `candidate-details` collection into `candidates-profile` ,I tried my method but its not working.

Canidate Profile Schema

```
    candidateDetails:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"candidate-details"
    }
```

canidate details Schema

```
    firstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    lastName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    userName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    phoneNumber:{
        type:Number,
        unique:true,
        required:true,
        validate(value){
            if(value.toString().length !== 10){
                throw new Error('Phone number should be of 10 digits');
            }
        }
    },
    whatsappNumber:{
        type:Number,
        unique:true,
        required:true,
        validate(value){
            if(value.toString().length !== 10){
                throw new Error('Phone number should be of 10 digits');
            }
        },
    },
    candidateId:{
        type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    }
```

```
const CandidateRegisterationModel= model('candidate-details',candidateRegisterationSchema);
```

controller function

```
const getAllCandidateProfiles=async(req,res)=>{
    const allCandidateData=await CandidateProfileModel.find({}).populate({path:'candidateDetails',select:'firstName'});
    console.log("candidate data : ",allCandidateData);
    if(allCandidateData!==null){
        try{
            res.status(200).json({message:"all candidate data fetched successfully",data:allCandidateData});
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).json({error})
        }
    }
    else{
        res.status(404).json({message:"all candidate profile not found",statusCode:res.statusCode});
    }
}
```

reponse that I am getting

```
       {
            "_id": "6364ef2d6e7233453700052b",
            "email": "shekharjain@gmail.com",
            "designation": "Developer",
            "street": "Dosa Bldg, 2nd floor room no 20, opp sandhurst road railways statiomn",
            "locality": "Dongri",
            "state": "Maharahstra",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "pincode": 400009,
            "country": "India",
            "categories": "Development",
            "skills": [
                "backend",
                "frontend"
            ],
            "facebook": "www.facebook.com/mahir",
            "linkedin": "www.linkedin.com/mahir",
            "github": "www.github.com/mahir",
            "twitter": "www.twitter.com/mahir",
            "instagram": "www.instagram.com/mahir",
            "website": "www.mahirjain",
            "candidateId": "6364ea62823a7fc21c561e06",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

Have many object like this in an array in  response

I really need your help . I am not able to understand why I am facing this Problem

Comment: You need to populate the `candidateId` field also, correct?

Comment: yess i have to populate `candidateId` and `candidateDetails`

Comment: Ok, you didn't specify a `ref` for that field in the schema declaration. What model does it refer to?

Comment: for now i am assigning id manually and priority is `candidateDetails` as of now